# i just want to get past 3 months transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

need help. i just want to get past 3 months transaction.

```
SELECT * 
FROM transaction
WHERE TransactionDate >= GETDATE()-90
```

transactionDate is a INT type with this format YYYYMMDD (ex. 20160812)

i got this error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

any help will do

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data.  The issue is clearly `TransactionDate`, but your question doesn't have enough information to provide an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't convert an int directly to a date.  However, you can convert a string in YYYYMMDD format.  So, try this:

```
WHERE cast(cast(TransactionDate as varchar(255)) as date) >= GETDATE() - 90
```

Alternatively, you could do all the conversion on the current date side:

```
WHERE TransactionDate >= CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), GETDATE() - 90, 112))
```

The advantage of this method is that the engine can use an index on `TransactionDate`.

That said, the right way to store the column is as a `DATE`.  SQL Server has built-in date/time data types for a reason; there is a lot of direct support for them.  Use the capabilities of the database.

Comment: @SquallLionheart, If this answer is useful to you, mark it as an answer.